# How to pass value from one window to another?

Tags: angularjs

I need on click to open new window and pass $scope values to that window.How can i do that?

Im using this code:

```
 $scope.ConfirmTicketPayOut = function (pinTicket, username)
    {
        $scope.pinTicket = pinTicket;

        accountDataProviderService.confirmTicketPayOut($scope.terminalId, pinTicket, username)
        .then(function (response) {

            $scope.confirmTicketPayOut = response;
            if ($scope.confirmTicketPayOut.Result == true)
            {

                $window.open('/ticketprint'); 

            }


        });
    }
```

So i need to pass `$scope.pinTicket` to another window

Comment: Is the other page outside of your Single Page Application. Changing the URL doesn't seem very Angular to me..

Comment: what u mean by that?

Comment: In SPAs you normally manage your views through some mechanism other than changing the window location. In angular you might show content through a directive or using ng-router/ui-router routes. Effectively this means you never change the window location but instead inject new views based on the state of the javascript.

Comment: im using ui.routes ...but now i need to open new window...with print option but when i use this $window.open().print(); i get blank page with print option if u know what i mean?